# Scala converting Map[String, Long] into JSON or JSON string

Tags: json, scala

I have a this object:

```
case class UserStateSummaryByHourPayload (
        ownerid: String,
        userid: String,
        team: String,
        profile: String,
        day: String,
        hour: Int,
        sortdate: String,
        month: String,
        durationpayload: Map[String, Long],
        maxdurationpayload: Map[String, Long]
    )
```

I would like to turn the two Map attributes into JSON or a string (writing to mysql column) such as this

```
case class JunkTest (
        ownerid: String,
        userid: String,
        team: String,
        profile: String,
        day: String,
        hour: Int,
        sortdate: String,
        month: String,
        durationpayload: String,
        maxdurationpayload: String
    )
```

I tried to do something like this following some other peoples guides, but its not working:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule;
            import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

            @transient val mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule);

            var junktest = ussapayloads.map(a => new JunkTest(
                a.ownerid, 
                a.userid,
                a.team, 
                a.profile, 
                a.day, 
                a.hour, 
                a.sortdate, 
                a.month, 
                mapper.writeValueAsString(a.durationpayload),
                mapper.writeValueAsString(a.maxdurationpayload)
            ));
```

How to I take my Map[String, Long] and turn it into JSON or a JSON string?

```
Map("Online" -> 100,"Ready" -> 200)
{ "Online": 100, "Ready": 200 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [play-json](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaJson) it is really easy:

```
import play.api.libs.json.Json
Json.stringify(Json.toJsObject(Map("Online" -> 100, "Ready" -> 200)))
```

Code run can be found at [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/toshetah/vJu6A1PwS5aXscx5EnCB2Q/5);

BTW, the code you attached works completely fine. You can find it in [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/toshetah/vJu6A1PwS5aXscx5EnCB2Q/11).

In order to install play-json please add the following to your `build.sbt`:

```
resolvers += "play-json" at "https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.play/play-json"
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.9.1"
```

Comment: I get exceptions with my above code:
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.fasterxml.jackson.module.paranamer.shaded.CachingParanamer

Comment: @phattyD Are you sure? Do you have redundant imports? Can you reproduce this failure in [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/)?

Comment: Yes I am sure, it works in Scastie, but does not work in my lab environment.  I am trying implementations for the play-json and spray json now.  Just trying to find the statements for adding to my sbt build to import the packages

Comment: @phattyD, I added what you need in your `build.sbt`

Comment: Thanks Tomer! 
I ended up with errors: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: play.api.libs.json.Writes
I have tried importing play.api.libs.json._ and that didn't help. I had the same issues with the spray.json above.  Is there a jar I need to add to classpath?

Comment: No. Just importing `play.api.libs.json.Json` as written above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224294/discussion-between-phattyd-and-tomer-shetah).

Comment: Just as a note once I added in the jar file manually to the jars directory this worked perfect.  I am not sure as to why Maven did not pull it down.  I had to go find the jar on the web and copy it to my folder:  play-functional_2.11-2.7.4.jar  for my specific version.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go!

```
import spray.json._
import DefaultJsonProtocol._
object Demo1 extends App {
val keyValue = Map("Online" -> 100, "Ready" -> 200)
    
println(keyValue.toJson) //output {"Online":100,"Ready":200}
}
```